# Print out custom name of the month in php

Tags: php, date, monthcalendar

I can't figure it out! I've created an array of months in "Slovenian language" and now, I would want to display my month's name instead of the number. Instead of working, it writes out - 32014vEurope/Berlin11bEurope/BerlinWed and some more weird stuff, it should obviously print out November in my case. I would like to solve this problem with arrays, but It just wouldn0t convert the number of 'n' to the requested month.

```
function kliknjena($link, $mojster)
{
    $meseci[1] = "Januar";
    $meseci[2] = "Februar";
    $meseci[3] = "Marec";
    $meseci[4] = "April";
    $meseci[5] = "Maj";
    $meseci[6] = "Junij";
    $meseci[7] = "Julij";
    $meseci[8] = "Avgust";
    $meseci[9] = "September";
    $meseci[10] = "Oktober";
    $meseci[11] = "November";
    $meseci[12] = "December";

    $sql = "SELECT naslov, podnaslov, vsebina, ustvarjeno, slug FROM novica
            where slug = '$mojster'
            limit 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {

            echo "<h1>".$row["naslov"]."</h1>";
            $timestamp = strtotime($row["ustvarjeno"]);
            $m = date("n", $timestamp);
            echo date("d. $meseci[$m]; Y, H:i:s", $timestamp);
            echo "<p>".$row["podnaslov"]."</p>"."<br>";
            echo "<p>".$row["vsebina"]."</p>"."<br>";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the first argument for date();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
echo date('d. ', $timestamp) . $meseci[$m] . date('; Y, H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

What's happening is that the month name is being substituted into the `date()` argument, and then all the letters in the month are being treated as formatting characters, so they get replaced with the corresponding fields from the date and time.